# python matplotlib x-axis labels all displaying but 1

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two lists i'm doing a basic line chart with in ipython notebook. Should be basic, but I keep getting a screwed up x-axis like this... it should start with Saturday.

[image]

What's wrong with my code that's making my x-axis label all messed up? It should start with Saturday, the first value in my date_list.
(ignore the y-axis values here, i just made count_list values for this example.)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

count_list = [5,7,2,3,1,7,3]
date_list = ['Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,3.5))
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ticknumbs = np.arange(7)
ax.plot(ticknumbs, count_list, color='r', linewidth=1.0)
ax.set_xticklabels(date_list, rotation = 45) #WHHHHY ARENT U WORKING
ax.margins(x=0.05, y=0.05)
```

Answer (score 3):

Take out the `ax_margins()` line. You're clipping your first data point right off.

[image]

Comment: dang, knew it was simple. what  should i do if i want some extra space that the margins provides? CAN I HAVE IT ALL.

Comment: The plot looks fine without padding to me. Perhaps you want to make the axis smaller within the figure? (don't know how that works with the notebook).